# How to convert a buffer to string/number/date without knowing the original type

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I am writing a query service that connects to a HBase and supports different GET/POST queries. The retrieved data is an array of objects where the key is the name of the column and the value is a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

However, a simple `columns[columnName].toString()` for each column of an object doesn't work, since there are fields that can be string, date or numbers. `.toString` works okay for string/date, but the numbers are returned in a format like this: `"all": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\ufffd",`.

A brute force (I do realize it's not a pretty code I was testing things) approach was something like this:

```
function parseEntry(entry) {
    let parsed = {};
    Object.keys(entry.columns).forEach(column => {
        const value = entry.columns[column].value;
        parsed[column] = (typeof value === 'object' && value.length <= 8) ?
            value.readInt32BE(4) :
            value.toString();

    });

    return parsed;
}
```

But sometimes I get strings whose length is `< 8` and I'll try to convert them to numbers, undesired behavior. I also tried to test the value with a regex like `/[^\u0000-\uffff]+/.test(value)` but for some reason the tests return false for every entry.

I tried every possible combination of `.toString`, `JSON.parse`, `.trim`, `readInt32BE` etc. but I did not succeed to properly parse an object like this. Is there a way to properly do it without a lot of if conditionals based on the name of the column?

**Edit**:
An entry in my response array looks like this (if it helps you to test things; I stripped some fields for security purposes; `all` should be a number, `cUS` and `fs` should be dates, `fqdn` it's a string and `val` is an IP which is also a string).

```
{ 'd:all': 
      { value: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 8e>,
        timestamp: [Int64 value:1553606385109 octets:00 00 01 69 ba 28 1d d5] },
     'd:cUS': 
      { value: <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 33 2d 32 36 54 31 32 3a 35 36 3a 30 39 2e 31 37 37 5a>,
        timestamp: [Int64 value:1553604980146 octets:00 00 01 69 ba 12 ad b2] },
     'd:fqdn': 
      { value: <Buffer 61 70 69 2d 67 6c 6f 62 61 6c 2e 6e 65 74 66 6c 69 78 2e 63 6f 6d>,
        timestamp: [Int64 value:1553606699454 octets:00 00 01 69 ba 2c e9 be] },
     'd:fs': 
      { value: <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 33 2d 32 32 54 31 35 3a 30 30 3a 31 33 2e 35 30 32 5a>,
        timestamp: [Int64 value:9005645987910764 octets:00 1f fe 96 5a 15 14 6c] },
     'd:val': 
      { value: <Buffer 35 32 2e 32 30 39 2e 31 33 30 2e 31 37 32>,
        timestamp: [Int64 value:1553606699454 octets:00 00 01 69 ba 2c e9 be] },
}
```

Comment: You can pass the type as a parameter `.toString('ascii')`, by default it uses `utf8`. If that doesn't work, you could do `parseInt(columns[columnName].toString('hex'), 16)`

Comment: @kemicofa this means I have to previously know the name of the columns that are string, right?

Comment: Well, you apparantely already do *all should be a number, cUS and fs should be dates, fqdn it's a string and val is an IP which is also a string).*

Comment: @kemicofa this is only for one table in the database. There are more. I'd like to write reusable code, not to have a lot of if conditionals. My intuition says that you can't really do this, some bytes are just some bytes, you give them meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your string to a number with the following. `\u0000` represents one character so you simply need to use `.` to match it. Then using [String#charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) you can transform it to a number.

> The charCodeAt() method returns an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index.

```js
const res = "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\ufffd"
.match(/./g)
.map(v=>v.charCodeAt());

console.log(res);
```

But in general, you'll need conditions to check to see what method you should use to convert the buffer.

Which can be done with [Buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) package, by passing the type (hex, binary, utf8 (default), or ascii) as a parameter.